# How to study efficiently?

Tags: soft-question

I have seen many child prodigy which learn and understand mathematics to a greater extent and with small amount of time.  Many of them in their late 20's were famous mathematician. I am as a ordinary mind person try to learn mathematics by **working hard** so that i can contribute significant to the mathematics society. Some times I think that there may be a way to rise-myself equal to child prodigies by working little organized and smarter way, but most of the time i also felt that no matter whatever I do i will not be as significant as prodigies. I try to read more and more maths on daily basis and try to prove theorem's on daily basis.

**Question :** How someone with ordinary mind can do significant contribution in mathematics ?

Just on smaller note I study and learn things related to Algebra.

Comment: ordinary minded person can not make significant contribution in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such a thing as an "ordinary mind;" everyone has a unique way of thinking and observing. Sometimes all a problem needs is a new perspective and that won't always (or even most of the time) be seen by "child prodigies." A solution could come from your specific way of interpreting the problem that no one else was able to perceive. Math has been around for a **very** long time, so sometimes the problems that have been unanswered for centuries just need someone to look at them with a new perspective.